# Upload a file along with other string parameters in android

Tags: android, file-upload, upload, android-volley, zip

I have to upload a file and has three more parameters which is `string`.The file can be image or `zip`.How is it possible with `volley` to upload a `file` and submit `string` parameters along with it when button is clicked?

I have also tried this link-https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/upload-pdf-file-server-android/
       Please help me.Thanks!!
              My code is:

```
                       public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment implements 
                               AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

                          EditText subj,desx;
                  private ImageView mAvatarImage;
                   Button choosefile,select,submt;
                      String uid, type;
                     String MY_PREFS_NAME = "value";
                  private int PICK_PDF_REQUEST = 1;
                  TextView filetext;
//storage permission code
              private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;
                 String uploadId;

//Uri to store the image uri
                  private Uri filePath;
               Spinner spinner,spinner2;
                       public Tab1Fragment() {
                  // Required empty public constructor
              }
            public static Tab1Fragment newInstance() {
             Tab1Fragment fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
              return fragment;
         }



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, 
     false);
         subj=(EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.subj);
             choosefile=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.choosefile);
                   select=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.select);
            submt=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.submt);
                 filetext=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.filetext);
            mAvatarImage=(ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.image);
             desx=(EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.desx);
          submt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveProfileAccount();
        }
    });
    select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
    });
    choosefile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadMultipart();
        }
    });
    requestStoragePermission();

    SharedPreferences prefs = 
 this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 
 Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    uid = prefs.getString("uid", null);
    spinner = (Spinner)rootview.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
     spinner2 = (Spinner)rootview.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> deparment= new ArrayList<String>();
    deparment.add("Support");
    deparment.add("Project");

    deparment.add("Payment");
    deparment.add("Service");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, deparment);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    List<String> priority= new ArrayList<String>();
        priority.add("low");
             priority.add("Medium");

              priority.add("High");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, priority);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);

    return rootview;
}

private void saveProfileAccount() {

    VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.UPLOAD_SUPPORT, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String resultResponse = new String(response.data);
            try {
                JSONObject b = new JSONObject(resultResponse);
                int status = b.getInt("status");
                String data = b.getString("message");
                Log.d("Response", data);
                if (status ==100) {
                  /*  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Skills.class);
                    startActivity(intent);*/

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            String errorMessage = "Unknown error";
            if (networkResponse == null) {
                if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                    errorMessage = "Request timeout";
                } else if (error.getClass().equals(NoConnectionError.class)) {
                    errorMessage = "Failed to connect server";
                }
            } else {
                String result = new String(networkResponse.data);
                try {
                    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
                    String status = response.getString("status");
                    String message = response.getString("message");

                    Log.e("Error Status", status);
                    Log.e("Error Message", message);

                    if (networkResponse.statusCode == 404) {
                        errorMessage = "Resource not found";
                    } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 401) {
                        errorMessage = message+" Please login again";
                    } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 400) {
                        errorMessage = message+ " Check your inputs";
                    } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 500) {
                        errorMessage = message+" Something is getting wrong";
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.i("Error", errorMessage);
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("userid", uid);
            params.put("department", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            params.put("priority", 
           spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());

            params.put("subject", subj.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("description",desx.getText().toString().trim());
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
            // for now just get bitmap data from ImageView
            params.put("avatar", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getContext(), mAvatarImage.getDrawable()), "*/*"));


            return params;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);

}
```

Comment: have a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32265639/5110595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 public void fileUploadFunction() {

    // Getting file path using Filepath class.
    Pdfuri = FilePath.getPath(this, uri);
    Log.d("Pdfuri", Pdfuri);

    // If file path object is null then showing toast message to move file into internal storage.
    if (Pdfuri == null) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please move your PDF file to internal storage & try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    // If file path is not null then PDF uploading file process will starts.
    else {

        try {

            PdfID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();


            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, PdfID, AppConstants.URL)
                            .addFileToUpload(Pdfuri, "pdf")
                            .addParameter("course", course.trim())
                            .addParameter("course_id", c_id.trim())
                            .addParameter("stream", stream.trim())
                            .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                            .setMaxRetries(5)
                            .startUpload();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception exception) {

            Toast.makeText(this, 
                   exception.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: It works fine upto android 7 using net.gotev:uploadservice:3.4.2 , but Oreo and Pie  net.gotev:uploadservice:3.4.2 Not Worked. Can Help Anyone

Answer (score 0):

```
VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        //Read response here
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        //Add post values here
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
        Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
        // Add you file here
        return params;
    }
};

VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```

You can use multipart for this. Here is a sample code